# C socket - Difference between sending and receiving time

Tags: performance, tcp, wifi, send, recv

I'm working with two devices, that have their clock correctly synchronized (offset less than 1 ms). I need to send `180KB`, using WiFi (estimated bandwidth is about *20Mb/s*).

I'm using the C function send (with *TCP*) on the sender, the recv on the receiver. Since the two clock are synchronized, I expect that the sending time and the receiving time should be the same (without taking into account the propagation time).

However, I obtained that the receiving time is 10ms-15ms higher than the sending time, and considering that the estimated sending/receiving time should be about `60ms`, this difference is quite high. I don't think that the problem is due to the processing through the *TCP* stack on the receiver.

Any idea?

Comment: Good old [Nagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)?

Comment: Hope this link helps you understand,

[http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/203157/does-data-size-in-tcp-udp-make-a-difference-on-transmission-time][1]


  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/203157/does-data-size-in-tcp-udp-make-a-difference-on-transmission-time

Comment: Didn't get which are the "several factors" that make the two elapsed time (send and recv) quite different..anyone else?